# integral over a subset of interval in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider a finite interval  $[0,d]$, where $d$ is a positive real number.

Let $K$ be a measurable subset of $[0,d]$

Then, how can I prove or disprove that $\int_Kx \,dx \geq \int^{m(K)}_0 x\,dx$, where $m(\cdot)$ denotes the Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_K x \,dx &=\int_{K\cap [0,m(K)]} x\,dx + \int_{K\cap [m(K), d]} x \,dx\\
&\ge \int_{K\cap [0,m(K)]} x\,dx + m(K) m(K \cap [m(K), d])  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)\\
&= \int_{K\cap [0,m(K)]} x\,dx + m(K) m([0, m(K)] \setminus K)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2) \\
&\ge \int_{K\cap [0,m(K)]} x\,dx + \int_{[0, m(K)]\setminus K} x \,dx\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)\\
&= \int_0^{m(K)} x\,dx.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

**Remark**

(1): As $x\ge m(K)$ on $K\cap [m(K), d]$, 
$$ \int_{K\cap [m(K), d]} x \,dx \ge  \int_{K\cap [m(K), d]} m(K) \,dx = m(K) m(K\cap [m(K), d])$$

(2) Note that $K \subset [0,d] = [0,m(K)] \cup [m(K), d]$, so 
$$m(K) = m(K \cap [0, m(K)]) + m(K \cap [m(K), d])$$
On the other hand, 
$$m(K) = m([0,m(K)]) = m(K\cap [0, m(K)]) + m([0,m(K)]\setminus K)$$
This two equalities implies 
$$m(K \cap [m(K), d]) = m([0,m(K)]\setminus K).$$

(3) Similar as (1), as $x \le m(K)$ on $[0,m(K)]$, we have 
$$\int_{[0, m(K)]\setminus K} x \,dx \le \int_{[0, m(K)]\setminus K}  m(K) \,dx = m(K) m([0,m(K)]\setminus K)$$

Comment: Since $x \ge m(K)$ there.@user12345678910 (And similar for that second inequality).

Comment: May I ask, from the perspective of someone who has not yet studied Lebesgue measure in detail (I'm currently reading about it), what $m\left(K\cap\left[m\left(K\right),d\right]\right)$ looks like? Or perhaps you might provide a bit of an explanation of this statement? I understand the first step of your work, but I don't understand the second-half of the second line yet.

Comment: @jm324354 The answer is updated. Please feel free to ask if necessary.

Comment: @John thank you so much!